# How to close the Webview at some point in Flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, url-launcher

I'm using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to show the webview inside the app to do the payment, After completion of the payment I have to navigate back to the previous screen. Is there any possibility to do this? Should it be handled from webview or mobile app?

This is the way that im using to show webview

```
_launchURL(onboardingLink) async {
   await canLaunch(onboardingLink)? 
     await launch(onboardingLink,
                  enableJavaScript: true,
                  forceWebView: true)
            : throw 'Could not launch $onboardingLink';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS

```
_onUrlChanged =
    flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) async {
  if (mounted) {
    //print("URL changed: $url");
    if (url.startsWith(paymentSuccessUrl)) {
        // handle success case
    } else if (if (paymentCancelUrl)) {
        // Handle cancel case
    }
  }
```

Comment: I couldnt use this now. Can you give updated solution for this?